# Scroll content over fixed background image in swift

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

I am trying to achieve a scrolling over a fixed image, as you can see on the picture.

[image]

I thought I should use a  scrollview but I didn't quite get it how to use it and what to include into the scrollview, since the image and the button on the bottom should be fixed. In addition, the content should only be scrollable, when the text is to long.

Comment: Why you don't use a UITextView ? It will be more simple.

Comment: I implemented this before, but on the Iphone 5 there is almost no place for the text, so it would look better with the scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution here would be using a `UITableView` inside a `UIViewController`.

You can then set up the cells to make it look exactly the way you want.

For instance the first cell would just be the image, the second cell would be your title, the third one would be your menu bar, and so on.

This may be really useful if you plan to present dynamically the elements inside your `UIViewController` (for example if you need to use a database, you may want to animate the insertion of the rows only if the content has be downloaded already)

So using a `UIViewController`, you can just add the `UITableView` to it and set it up using contraints so that it fills the entire view. Then you can just add your button on the top of your table view, as a subview of your `UIViewController`'s `view` (not as a subclass of your table view otherwise your button would end up scrolling too). 
And again here you would need to add a few constraints to your button to make it look alright!

Just try it like this and let me know if you have any difficulties in the implementation :)

Comment: But the image should be fixed so I can't put it inside a cell I think. Should I also make it a subview of the viewcontroller?

Comment: Oh I misunderstood your question then, do you want your image to be fixed at the top of the screen ? (that's not how it looks on the image though so It might be a little bit misleading)

Comment: I mean, I want it fixed behind the cell, so that the content flows over the image. You get, what I mean?

Comment: I see! and what if the user scrolls the whole way down to the bottom, do you still want your header to be visible a little bit (like on your second omage) or will it be completely hidden behind at some point ?

Comment: If there's enough text it should be hidden.

Comment: Okay I will create a little project by tomorrow and will keep you posted then :)

Answer (score 0):

It is very complex to explain, To understand you must know good autolayout

To achieve that you need two **scrollview**  and little math :)

Suppose your **headerview** height is 200

As you know when using autolayout we need following view hierarchy

Your view Hierarchy should be

```
--> Main View
 --> ScrollView  
  --> Container View
     -->Your HeaderView (200)
     -->Content View (Equal height to UIView)
        --> UIView (Your tabs like button , followbutton)
        --> ScrollView 2
           --> ContainerView     
             -->Subviews
```

Scroll view 1 Will used wo scroll the headerview and second scrollview will used to scroll other content of scrollview (Like Tab and text content as shown in picture  )

**Content View (Equal height to UIView)** will allow your content view to give height of 200 extra  to scroll bottom and your second scrollview will scroll to  top which will allow to scroll your other content too

https://media.giphy.com/media/a2A4AQeAIkAhO/giphy.gif

[image]